# Only select rows from current page using checkbox on header in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am facing an issue related to Ag-grid is that when we check the checkbox from header then they select all total records (all pages in pagination) I just want to select the current page data for ex: I have 10 records in page number 1 then they should select only 10 records in a grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating solution for your problem I chose Custom Components, that will help to define custom header renderer to use at the column definition level.

CustomHeader will be in charge of the checkbox display in the grid - full definition is available in example at the end of the post:

```js
  CustomHeader.prototype.init = function(params) { ... }
```

Checkboxes are shown in first column (using `isFirstColumn` function) and will be refreshed on each pagination change
or checkbox selection (`onPaginationChanged` `onSelectionChanged`).
This is compulsory, as element needs to be checked only if all rows are selected.

> `refreshHeader()` Redraws the header. Useful if a column name changes, or something else that changes how the column header is displayed.

```js
  // grid definition
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    ...
    defaultColDef: {
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      resize: true,
      checkboxSelection: isFirstColumn
    },
    onPaginationChanged: onPaginationChanged,
    onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged
  };

  // events handlers
  function onSelectionChanged(event) {
    this.api.refreshHeader();
  }

  function onPaginationChanged(event) {
    this.api.refreshHeader();
  }

  function isFirstColumn(params) {

    return params.column.colId === "make";

    //Previous implementation with detecting
    //first column but slows down the grid
    //var displayedColumns = params.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns();
    //var thisIsFirstColumn = displayedColumns[0] === params.column;
    //return thisIsFirstColumn;
  }
```

[Working example AngularJs](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-gridpaginationselection59298385-vub53?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[Working example Angular5](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular5-aggrid-59298385-l8ym1)

Comment: Thanks to @kamil-kubicki but can you please provide your solution in angular 4or 5 version

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas - post was updated with new example based on Angular 5 - please note that I'm not Angular 5 developer (some aspects of the code might be discussed), but example works fine.

Comment: @kami-kubicki Thank you so much you save my day

Comment: I've found that suggested solution (isFirstColumn implementation) significantly slowdowns performance on scrolling

Comment: Hi fedor, thanks for feedback - just updated and remplaced by 'return params.column.colId === "make";' avoiding nested getAllDisplayedColumns() calls for each column.

Comment: Thanks for posting this @SiddharthVyas I found it very helpful.   How can I access from the main component if the select all checkbox is selected?  In my case I need to on each pagination keep all rows selected if its checked not refresh.

Answer (score 4):

Simple code-based solution (may not work well with Grouping, test yourself) without need for any custom component:

Attach `paginationChanged` event listener to `onGridReady` Grid event:

```
onGridReady = (params) =>
{
    this.gridApi.addEventListener('paginationChanged', (e) =>
        {
            //Reset rows selection based on current page
            this.resetPaginationSelection(this);
        });
};
```

Event Handler method for handling selectable rows in current page:

```
resetPaginationSelection = (self) =>
{
    //Deselect previously selected rows to reset selection
    self.gridApi.deselectAll();

    //Initialize pagination data
    let paginationSize = self.gridApi.paginationGetPageSize();
    let currentPageNum = self.gridApi.paginationGetCurrentPage();
    let totalRowsCount = self.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount();

    //Calculate current page row indexes
    let currentPageRowStartIndex = (currentPageNum * paginationSize);
    let currentPageRowLastIndex = (currentPageRowStartIndex + paginationSize);
    if(currentPageRowLastIndex > totalRowsCount) currentPageRowLastIndex = (totalRowsCount);

    for(let i = 0; i < totalRowsCount; i++)
    {
        //Set isRowSelectable=true attribute for current page rows, and false for other page rows
        let isWithinCurrentPage = (i >= currentPageRowStartIndex && i < currentPageRowLastIndex);
        self.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i).setRowSelectable(isWithinCurrentPage);
    }
};
```